# Regex to remove strings

Tags: regex, string, replace

I have i.e. this string:

```
<span value="Abel" class="select-item ">Abel<span class="cd-dropdown-option"></span></span>
```

I want to remove all except 'Abel'.
With which regex I can achieve that?

Comment: Just for clarification: Another string would be '<span value="Alice" class="select-item ">Alice<span class="cd-dropdown-option"></span></span>' and I want to remove all except 'Alice' (that is the text itself).

Comment: unclear what you are asking... 1) you have two Abel/Alice in your string, which do you want? 2) if it is xml/html, use the corresponding parser

Comment: `span.textContent`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I can understand - you just want to remove all html tags from your strings. While it is better to use some html parser in most cases, you can try to use `<.*?>` regular expression and remove its matches.